# re-rendering issues when using HOC for loader

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, immutable.js, higher-order-components

I am building an app where there is tons of pages and each page needs loader icon to show when the data is coming from server but has not arrived yet but no content is shown if there is no data at all. I could show this without using Higher Order Component(HOC) with no problem but doing so in every component is tedious. I want the loader code be reusable so that i can use this in every component wherever needed. But I am facing the problem.

> If there is data, there is no issue. If there is no data at all, then
>   the loader keeps loading and loading instead should show no content.

I had to use `if (!this.props.size)` inside componentDidMount to fetch the data because if i dont do this, the component will be re-rendering continuously and if i do this, the component will not re-render if there is data but if there is no data at all, the component gets re-rendered continuously with loading icon.

Here is the code

```
class Logs extends React.PureComponent {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      show: false,
    };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    // this.props.requestLogs();
    if (!this.props.logs.size) {
      this.props.requestLogs();
    }
  }

  //componentWillUnmount() {
    //document.body.removeEventListener("", this.props.requestLogs());
  //}


  renderLogs() {
    const { logs } = this.props;
    return logs.size > 0
      ? logs.valueSeq().map(log => {
          return (
            <div className="card" key={log.get("_id")}>
              <li className="row">
                <div className="col-md-6">
                  <a
                    onClick={() =>
                      this.handleDialog(log.get("_id"), log.get("error_stack"))}
                  >
                    {log.get("error_message")}
                  </a>
                </div>
                <div className="col-md-6 text-right">
                  <a
                    className="text-danger"
                    onClick={() => this.handleDelete(log.get("_id"))}
                  >
                    Delete
                  </a>
                </div>
              </li>
            </div>
          );
        })
      : <p>No Content</p>;
  }
  render() {
    const { logs, isRequesting } = this.props;
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <div className="row mg-btm-md">
          <div className="col-xs-6"> <h1>Logs</h1></div>
        </div>
        <ul className="list-group">
          {this.renderLogs()}
          {this.state.show ? this.props.dialog : null}
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(
  Loader("isRequesting")(Logs)
);


const Loader = prop => WrappedComponent => {
  return class Loader extends React.PureComponent {
    render() {
      return this.props[prop]
        ? <div className="earth-spinning">
            <img
              src={EarthSpinning}
              alt="spinner"
              style={{ margin: "0 auto" }}
            />
          </div>
        : <WrappedComponent {...this.props} />;
    }
  };
};

export default Loader;
```

complete code is here `https://gist.github.com/SanskarSans/b30c085ffacf01c58b66f128096746cc`

Comment: show the "mapStateToProps" function, I cant see your "isRequesting" variable...

Comment: I dont know why you made such complexity to such a component. Simplify your code first.

Comment: Can you give me an idea where should i improve, please?

Comment: The problem is in componentDidMount i think but could not resolve issue

Comment: I'll add an example of how I'll do it, it really doesn't matter with redux or others.  You should 2 components that work properly. After that add redux

Answer (score 0):

I did something super simple, and there is surely places to improve.
But it solved the issues you wanted, if you have a flag of "loadedData" you show the data, if not you show a loader.

link to code:
https://codepen.io/tzookb/pen/VWdeyE

code:

```
class SomeComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <div>Im a basic component</div>;
  }
}

function withLoader(WrappedComponent) {
  return class extends React.Component {
    render() {
      if (this.props.loadedData) {
        return <WrappedComponent {...this.props} />;        
      } else {
        return <h1>Loading...</h1>;
      }
    }
  };
}

let SomeComponentWithLoader = withLoader(SomeComponent);


ReactDOM.render(<SomeComponentWithLoader loadedData={false} />, document.getElementById("app"));
```