# pass props to selectors to filter based on that props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, reselect

I need to pass props to selectors so that i can fetch the content of the clicked item from the selectors. However i could not pass the props. I tried this way but no success

```
const mapStateToProps = createStructuredSelector({
  features: selectFeatures(),
  getFeatureToEditById: selectFeatureToEditById(),
});

handleFeatureEdit = (event, feature) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  console.log("feature handle", feature);
  const dialog = (
    <FeatureEditDialog
      feature={feature}
      featureToEdit={selectFeatureToEditById(feature)}
      onClose={() => this.props.hideDialog(null)}
    />
  );
  this.props.showDialog(dialog);
};

selectors.js

const selectFeatureState = state => state.get("featureReducer");

const selectFeatureById = (_, props) => {
  console.log("props", _, props); #if i get the id of feature here
  # i could then filter based on that id from below selector and show 
  # the result in FeatureEditDialog component 
};

const selectFeatureToEditById = () =>
  createSelector(
    selectFeatureState,
    selectFeatureById,
    (features, featureId) => {
      console.log("features", features, featureId);
    }
  );
```

Here is the gist for full code

https://gist.github.com/MilanRgm/80fe18e3f25993a27dfd0bbd0ede3c20

Comment: Please add more code..

Comment: updated my question with the full code @SantoshRamKunjir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply pass both state and props from your `mapStateToProps` to your selectors.

If you use a selector directly as the mapStateToProps function, it will receive the same arguments mapState does: `state` and `ownProps` (props set on the connected component).

A simple example:

```
// simple selector
export const getSomethingFromState = (state, { id }) => state.stuff[id]
// reselect selector
export const getStuff = createSelector(
  getSomethingFromState,
  (stuff) => stuff
)

// use it as mapDispatchToProps
const mapDispatchToProps = getSomethingFromState

const MyContainer = connect(mapDispatchToProps)(MyComponent)

// and set id as an own prop in the container when rendering
<MyContainer id='foo' />
```

However you're doing some weird things like mapping a selector to reuse it later. It doesn't work that way, at least it's not intended to be used that way.

You use selectors to retrieve slices of your state and pass it as props to your `connect`ed components. Whenever the state changes, your selectors will be re-run (with some caching thanks to reselect). If something the component is actually retrieving from Redux has changed indeed, it will re-render.

So your `FeatureEditDialog` component should be connected as well, and should be capable of retrieving anything it needs from the Redux state, just by using props (which feature, which id, so on) in its own `connect` call.

`this.props.showDialog(dialog);` is a big code smell as well. ;)

Comment: Thanks for sharing knowledge. I am trying to learn all the great packages like reselect, immutable, saga. I got the concept of selectors now. If you have time, can you please look at this ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44895561/re-rendering-issues-when-using-hoc-for-loader

Comment: If the answer is valid you should mark it as answered.